# Photoshop inner shadow affecting another layer's drop shadow

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I applied drop shadow to a layer. Then I created a new layer and tried to apply an inner shadow to it. Turns out, that changing the angle on the new layer also effects the angle of the other layer' drop shadow!

The two layers are not linked in any way. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why when I change a drop shadow do all my drop shadows change?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74725/why-when-i-change-a-drop-shadow-do-all-my-drop-shadows-change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this is solved. I had to uncheck the 'Use Global Light' option in the Blending Options panel. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yeah. I always turn Use Global Light off. I don't see any real world use for the feature.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, unchecking Global Light is key. You can check it for one group and leave others unchecked if you want that group to have the same angle of blending effect. However, I have found that Bevel-Emboss can get really messed up this way, as it doesn't account for foreground background perspective. It helps a LOT on drop shadow so it doesn't look like all your objects/layers have different light sources (it provides a much more realistic shadow when you implant multiple objects in a scene). THANK you for posting this as the words "Global Light" are not intuitive as to what they will do to your effects!