# Do different drop shadow effects have to stay the same on copies of the original layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am making a duplicate of a layer which has layer style effects (drop shadow). Next, I'm changing the angle of the drop shadow on that new layer. However, when I do that, the angle changes on the original layer as well. How can I change the copies' angle to my liking, without affecting the original layer's drop shadow angle?

I have tried copy/pasting the layer, making a duplicate, going with CTRL+J, creating a completely unrelated layer (shape, importing from another document, etc) and it was always the same, as if the drop shadow angle was a global setting.

I know that I could rasterize the original layer, and then change what I need on the copy, but I'd rather keep it as it is.

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why when I change a drop shadow do all my drop shadows change?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74725/why-when-i-change-a-drop-shadow-do-all-my-drop-shadows-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck **Use Global Light** in the Layer Styles Window for the Drop Shadow.

[image]

This allows you to set shadow angles independently of any other layers which *is* using the Global Light.